# How to resample DatetimeIndex in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

How can I resample `DatetimeIndex` objects in Pandas? Assume I have some existing `DatetimeIndex` object called `oldindex`. I would like to have the index that would be the result if I ran:

```
newindex = pd.Series(index=oldindex, data=None).resample('H').sum().index
```

But this solution does unnecessary computation (i.e., constructs a series and calculates sums) and it just looks ugly. Unfortunately, `newindex = oldindex.resample('H')` doesn't work, although I don't see any reason why it or something similar couldn't work in principle. For resampling the index, it doesn't matter what the operation (sum, mean, ffill, ...) would be.

Comment: I don't think that's what I want at all if I understood you correctly. First, what is `df` here? I hadn't defined any `df` in my example. And how does that command know to what frequency to resample to? Could you write a complete example how to use `reindex` to convert `oldindex` to the same `newindex` result as I gave?

Answer (score 0):

Resampling is to *change the data*, if you have no data to change you can just create a new index with the required frequency that covers the original range:

```
>>> oldindex
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04',
               '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08',
               '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
>>> newindex = pd.date_range(start=oldindex[0], end=oldindex[-1], freq='H')
>>> newindex
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2020-01-01 02:00:00', '2020-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2020-01-01 04:00:00', '2020-01-01 05:00:00',
               '2020-01-01 06:00:00', '2020-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2020-01-01 08:00:00', '2020-01-01 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2020-01-09 15:00:00', '2020-01-09 16:00:00',
               '2020-01-09 17:00:00', '2020-01-09 18:00:00',
               '2020-01-09 19:00:00', '2020-01-09 20:00:00',
               '2020-01-09 21:00:00', '2020-01-09 22:00:00',
               '2020-01-09 23:00:00', '2020-01-10 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=217, freq='H')
```

(instead of `oldindex[0]` and `oldindex[-1]` you could also use `oldindex.min()` and `oldindex.max()` for clarity)

Comment: This isn't correct. Here's a trivial counter-example: `oldindex = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2020-05-15 09:42", "2020-05-15 10:01"])` (then use freq `H`). Also, it fails for empty `oldindex`, so you'd need to add special cases for that.

Comment: In addition to those issues, `name` attribute of `oldindex` is lost. But that can be given as `name=oldindex.name` argument to `pd.date_range`.